# ADF convertTimeZone Invalid Timezone ID

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I encounter this weird issue related on using convertTimeZone function in ADF.

convertTimeZone function expect 4 params which are timestamp string, source timezone, new timezone, date format

Refer to this document [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#convertTimeZone]

I keep receiving error

```
the function 'convertTimeZone', the value provided for the time zone id 'Singapore Standard Time' was not valid. "
```

I double check it whether the timezone I provided is in the microsoft time zone list

Refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones?view=windows-11

Which in this case is in the list. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below expression to convert UTC to 'Singapore Standard Time' time zone.

```
@string(convertTimeZone(utcnow(), 'UTC','Singapore Standard Time'))
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

Reference: [Microsoft Time Zone Index Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms912391(v=winembedded.11))